# Conditional probability distribution formulas

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I got the following question to solve:

> The time to fix a TV in hours, is an exponential random variable with parameter λ=$\frac{1}{2}$
>
> What is the probability that a repair will take more than 10 hours, if given it already takes 9 hours.

The answer is $e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

I followed [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) but nothing seems to work

I guess there's a formula for this but I didn't found one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponential distribution has the [memorylessness property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness), which is why the result appears not to care about the $9$ elapsed hours. To see why it is so, consider the following:

Let $X$ denote the time needed to fix the TV. Since $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}\left(\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\right)$, we have that $\mathrm{Pr}(X > x) = e^{- \lambda x}$. Now:

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Pr}(X > 10 \mid X > 9) & = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(X > 10, \, X > 9)}{\mathrm{Pr}(X > 9)} \\
& = \frac{\mathrm{Pr}(X > 10)}{\mathrm{Pr}(X > 9)} \\
& = \frac{e^{-10 \lambda}}{e^{-9 \lambda}} = e^{-\lambda} = \boxed{e^{-\frac{1}{2}}}
\end{align*}
$$

---

It should be intuitively clear that $\mathrm{Pr}(X > 10, \, X > 9) = \mathrm{Pr}(X > 10)$, but in case it is not: $\mathrm{Pr}(X > 10, \, X > 9) = \mathrm{Pr}(X > 10) \cdot \underbrace{\mathrm{Pr} (X > 9 \mid X > 10)}_{{} = 1} = \mathrm{Pr}(X > 10)$.

Comment: Thanks, what is the $\text{~}$ notation means?

Comment: No problem; glad to have helped. $X \sim \mathrm{Exp}\left(\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\right)$ means "$X$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$."